# How to present or plot results in this way ? (Python)

Tags: python, gnuplot

I have some results and i would like to present them in the same way like in the picture.

[image]

Any help how this could be best done using Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for radar charts in matplotlib - http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/radar_chart.html